# Hashmap error is not abstract and does not override method in remove() in iterator

Tags: java

So I am working on a hashmap that uses two distinct hash functions to create it. The problem is in my iterator class I am getting an error that reads `<anonymous hashmap.MyHashMap$1>` is not abstract and does not override method in `remove()` in iterator. I have tried everything to figure out how to get this error to go away. I cannot simply "implement all abstract methods" as it suggests as otherwise I can't initialize the hash function and use it to insert values. Below is the entirety of my code

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyHashMap<KeyType, ValueType> implements
    Iterable<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> {
    // The size of the array
    int theSize = 0;                                  
    // The starting size of the table
    public static final int DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE = 11;  
    // Array containing the number of nodes in each index of the array
    int lengths[] = null;                       
    // The array used for the hash table
    private Node<KeyType, ValueType>[] arr = null;  
    private HashFunction<KeyType> hash1;        //One of the two hash functions
    private HashFunction<KeyType> hash2;        //One of the two hash functions


    /**
     * Null constructor for the myHashMap object
     */
    public MyHashMap() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Accepts two hash functions to generate a hash code
     *
     * @param h1 The first hash function
     * @param h2 The second hash function
     */
    public MyHashMap(HashFunction<KeyType> h1, HashFunction<KeyType> h2) {
        hash1 = h1;
        hash2 = h2;

        doClear();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the table
     */
    public int size() {
        return theSize;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the clear private routine
     */
    public void clear() {
        doClear();
    }

    /**
     * Clears the table
     */
    private void doClear() {
        theSize = 0;
        arr = new Node[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE];
        lengths = new int[DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE];
    }

    /**
     * Resizes the hash table if the size passes the default size
     */
    private void rehash() {
        MyHashMap<KeyType, ValueType> bigger
            = new MyHashMap<KeyType, ValueType>(hash1, hash2);

        bigger.arr = new Node[arr.length * 2];
        bigger.lengths = new int[bigger.arr.length];

        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> lst : arr) {
            for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = lst; p != null; p = p.next) {
                bigger.put(p.key, p.value);
            }
        }

        arr = bigger.arr;
        lengths = bigger.lengths;

        bigger = null;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a hash code in order to determine where on the table the item
     * goes
     *
     * @param k The key that will be used to generate the code
     * @param h The hash function to be used
     * @return The index
     */
    private int myHash(KeyType k, HashFunction<KeyType> hash) {
        if (hash == null) {
            return Math.abs(k.hashCode() % arr.length);
        } else {
            return Math.abs(hash.hashCode(k) % arr.length);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Places an item into the hash map. If the key matches an existing one, the
     * value is then replaced with the new incoming value
     *
     * @param k The incoming key
     * @param v The incoming value
     * @return The the old value removed.
     */
    public ValueType put(KeyType k, ValueType v) {
        // If the size of the table exceeds the default array size, rehash
        if (size() > arr.length) {
            rehash();
        }

        // The hash codes obtained from the key
        int thisList1 = myHash(k, hash1);
        int thisList2 = myHash(k, hash2);

        // Checking if the incoming key matches an existing key, if it does
        // replace the value and return the old one
        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList1]; p != null; p = p.next) {
            if (p.key.equals(k)) {
                ValueType old = p.value;
                p.value = v;
                return old;
            }
        }

        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList2]; p != null; p = p.next) {
            if (p.key.equals(k)) {
                ValueType old = p.value;
                p.value = v;
                return old;
            }
        }

        // Adding the incoming data to the index with the least amount of 
        // nodes in it.
        if (numOfNodes(arr[thisList1]) <= numOfNodes(arr[thisList2])) {
            arr[thisList1] = new Node<>(k, v, arr[thisList1]);
            ++lengths[thisList1];
            ++theSize;
        } else {
        // Else the second list is the smaller of the two. Add it to this one
            arr[thisList2] = new Node<>(k, v, arr[thisList2]);
            ++lengths[thisList2];
            ++theSize;
        }

        // No old value to return
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Counts the number of nodes that exist in a space of the table
     *
     * @param n The start space
     * @return The number of nodes
     */
    private int numOfNodes(Node n) {
        int size = 0;

        // If the space is not empty, then it will step through and count the 
        // number of nodes present
        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = n; p != null; p = p.next) {
            ++size;
        }

        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Removes a specified key from the map
     * @param k The key that is to be removed
     * @return True if the object has been removed, false if it has not
     */
    public boolean remove(KeyType k) {
        // Getting the hash codes for the list
        int thisList1 = myHash(k, hash1);
        int thisList2 = myHash(k, hash2);

        // If the position specified by hash1 is found, check first element
        if (arr[thisList1] != null) {
            if (arr[thisList1].key.equals(k)) {
                arr[thisList1] = arr[thisList1].next;
                --theSize;
                return true;
            }
            for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList1]; p.next != null;
                    p = p.next) {
                if (p.next.key.equals(k)) {
                    p.next = p.next.next;
                    --theSize;
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        // If the position specified by hash2 is found, check first element
        if (arr[thisList2] != null) {
            if (arr[thisList2].key.equals(k)) {
                arr[thisList2] = arr[thisList2].next;
                --theSize;
                return true;
            }
            for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList2]; p.next != null;
                    p = p.next) {
                if (p.next.key.equals(k)) {
                    p.next = p.next.next;
                    --theSize;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Else the item that is to removed is never found, therefore return
        // false
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the desired value associated with the specified key
     *
     * @param k The key
     * @return The value if found, null if not
     */
    public ValueType get(KeyType k) {

        // The hash codes obtained from the key
        int thisList1 = myHash(k, hash1);
        int thisList2 = myHash(k, hash2);

        // Using the first hash code, searching the nodes
        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList1]; p != null; p = p.next) {
            if (p.key.equals(k)) {
                return p.value;
            }
        }

        // Using the second hash code, seraching the nodes
        for (Node<KeyType, ValueType> p = arr[thisList2]; p != null; p = p.next) {
            if (p.key.equals(k)) {
                return p.value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Prints out the hashMap
     *
     * @return The printed hashMap
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("[");
        for(Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> n : this) {
            sb.append(n);
            sb.append(",");
        }

        sb.append("]");

        return new String(sb);
    }

    /**
     * Creates an iterator for traversing the list.
     *
     * @return An iterator to traverse the list
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>>() {
            /**
             * Checks if the node has a next link
             * @return True if it has a node, false if it does not
             */
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != null;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the next item on the list
             * @return The next node
             */
            @Override
            public Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> next() {
                final Node<KeyType, ValueType> theCurrent = current;

                current = current.next;

                // If the current list has no more nodes, move to the next list
                if (current == null) {
                    ++listNum;
                    advanceToNewList();
                }

                // Creates a new entry that will hold the next node
                Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> nextItem = new Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>() {

                    /**
                     * Returns the current node's key
                     * @return 
                     */
                    @Override
                    public KeyType getKey() {
                        return theCurrent.key;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Returns the current node's value
                     * @return 
                     */
                    @Override
                    public ValueType getValue() {
                        return theCurrent.value;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Sets a new value to the current node
                     * @param value The new value that will be placed
                     * @return The old value that was overwritten 
                     */
                    @Override
                    public ValueType setValue(ValueType value) {
                        ValueType temp = theCurrent.value;
                        theCurrent.value = value;
                        return temp;
                    }
                };

                return nextItem;
            }

            /**
             * Advances to the next index of the table
             */
            private void advanceToNewList() {
                while (listNum < arr.length && arr[ listNum ] == null) {
                    listNum++;
                }

                if (listNum != arr.length) {
                    current = arr[listNum];
                }
            }

            // Initializes the advanceToNewList method {
                advanceToNewList();
            }

            Node<KeyType, ValueType> current;   // current node
            int listNum;                        // current list #
        };

    }

    /**
     * Creates a node class for the linked list
     * @param <KeyType> The key for the map. Can be any type
     * @param <ValueType> The value associated with the key. Can be any type
     */
    class Node<KeyType, ValueType> {

        /**
         * Constructs a node object using a key, a value, and a link to the next
         * node
         * @param k The key
         * @param v The value
         * @param n The next node
         */
        Node(KeyType k, ValueType v, Node<KeyType, ValueType> n) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
            next = n;
        }

        /**
         * Prints out the node 
         * @return A string containing the key and the value
         */
        public String toString() {
            return key + "=" + value;
        }

        KeyType key;                   // The key of the node
        ValueType value;               // The value of the node
        Node<KeyType, ValueType> next; // The next node
    }

    /**
     * Creates an array that contains the number of entries that have a
     * certain length. For example: The number of lists of length 0, 1, 2, etc. 
     * @return The array containing the distribution of list lengths
     */
    public int[] getLengths()
    {
        int sizeList[] = new int[20];

        // Incrementing the count at the index in the array sizeList. It will
        // increment for every list of size at lengths[i].
        for(int i = 0; i < lengths.length; ++i) {
            ++sizeList[lengths[i]];
        }

        return sizeList;
    }
}
```

Below is the specific location where the error occurs

```
public Iterator<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>>()
    {  <--- Right here is where the error occurs
```

Any help that can be provided will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  When creating anonymous classes of an interface, you must implement every abstract method. You don't necessarily need to thoroughly implement every method, you must just create it even if it has blank contents. So, you can just do this to rid the error (starting at the arrow where the exception was raised) :

```
  public void remove() {
   //No contents
   }
```

and do the same things for any other abstract methods in the Iterator interface. However, it is probably best that you do actually write some code for these...

Comment: Some cases, including Iterator's remove method, allow simply throwing UnsupportedOperationException.